# Change Krunner size and position in KDE Plasma 5

Tags: linux, kde, plasma, plasma5, kde5

Is it possible to change the Krunner position and size?

By default it is too close to top edge of the screen and it looks too small:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Position:

In plasma 5.20 and above the position can be switched between top and center as said [here](https://superuser.com/a/1486294/1039759)

[image]

In all Plasma 5 versions position can be set to middle by editing `~/.config/krunnerrc` and adding

```
[General]
FreeFloating=true
```

Then restart KRunner.

```
krunner --replace & disown
```

Other positions can be set with a window rule as said [here](https://superuser.com/a/1075753/1039759)

[image]

---

### Size:

It changes with the font. As said [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/cpsz6h/how_to_make_fonts_in_krunner_bigger_how_to_make/ewrdgdy?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3):

In `~/.config/krunnerrc` add this section:

```
[General]
font=Noto Sans,12,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0
```

> Generally, all configuration entries from ~/.config/kdeglobals can be
> overridden in per-application configuration files, including fonts,
> icons, and colors.

With a configuration for center and font 12, it looks like so:

[image]

Proportion may depend on the screen resolution. Font 20:

[image]

More condensed fonts can be used to fit longer lines (e.g. the full path of a file)

---

### UPDATE:

In Plasma 5.24, in case the above font size settings are not followed, check `~/.config/krunnerrc` and change so that you have `migrated=false` (instead of `true`).

---

To further adjust size (for example to make it close to full screen without increasing font size too much), a window rule will work. It should look like so (Plasma 5.24):

[image]

to create it quickly, pop the krunner, pin it (upper right pin), press Alt-F3, More actions - Configure special window setting, Add Property, and under "Size and position" select "Size". The search field will stay the same but the results will show the longer lines, like those of file and folder paths for example.